# PHP, MYSQL record not being updated

Tags: php, mysql

Here's another wierd one:

Here's my php:

```
$query = "SELECT iVal, iOwn FROM item WHERE item = ".$_GET['Item'];
$result9 = mysql_query($query, $_SESSION['connect']);
$row9 = mysql_fetch_array($result9);
$query = "UPDATE chars SET chCred = chCred + ".$row9['iVal']." WHERE chNum = ".$row9['iOwn'];
mysql_query($query, $_SESSION['connect']) or die('Error 2:'.mysql_error());
```

When I run it and do a var_dump on $query I get this:

```
UPDATE chars set chCred = chCred + 100000 WHERE chNum = 2
```

When I run this query in phpMyAdmin the record gets updated correctly but when I run the code the record isn't being updated and I get no error message.

Comment: Your first (`SELECT`) query is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You **really** should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: And what do you get if you use [some error handling](http://snipplr.com/view/45252/goede-foutafhandeling-mysql/)?

Comment: Also, use the link identifier for `mysql_error()` too. `mysql_error($_SESSION['connect'])`

Comment: has the session been started with ``session_start();`` ?

Comment: The session was started, I tried using the link identifier and still got no error message. I don't underdstand Bobby Tables or the error handling. Still gotta digest that. The thing is, I've been updating my tables the same way throughout my programs and this is the first time I've run into this problem.

Comment: Verify that `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` worked.

Comment: @S.e.Estes: My 'Bobby Tables' remark does not relate to the problem you're experiencing - rather a serious security vulnerability in your code that you should spend some time understanding and trying to fix.

Comment: how do I verify that mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db() worked?  I tried the error handling mentioned above but got no errors.

Comment: Duhhh. Turns out I was adding the value in then subtracting it out later. The code works as is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your database connection on the web server need you to manually COMMIT updates? If the SQL is working when you enter it manually, then either your database connection doesn't have autocommit set, or there's a problem with passing the query to the database, which you can check out by adding error handling, as others have said.